# No Persistence provider for EntityManager with JavaSE app?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, postgresql

I'm trying to set up simple `postgres` database with `Hibernate JPA` (local javaSE app, not container managed JEE). But I cannot even create the `EntityManager`. What might be wrong with the following?

Usage:

```
public MyDaoService() {
    EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("myapp");
    em = emf.createEntityManager();
}
```

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="myapp" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
       <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/travelport"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="postgres"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="postgres"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
      </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Maven config:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.8.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.8.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>9.3-1100-jdbc41</version>
</dependency>
```

Logs:

```
Jan 08, 2014 12:34:03 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.2.Final}
Jan 08, 2014 12:34:03 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.2.8.Final}
Jan 08, 2014 12:34:03 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Jan 08, 2014 12:34:03 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Jan 08, 2014 12:34:04 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Jan 08, 2014 12:34:04 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20
Jan 08, 2014 12:34:04 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000006: Autocommit mode: true
Jan 08, 2014 12:34:04 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000401: using driver [org.postgresql.Driver] at URL [jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/myapp]
Jan 08, 2014 12:34:04 PM org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
INFO: HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=postgres, password=****, autocommit=true, release_mode=auto}
Jan 08, 2014 12:34:04 PM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
INFO: HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
Jan 08, 2014 12:34:04 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder useContextualLobCreation
INFO: HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named myapp: Provider named org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence threw unexpected exception at create EntityManagerFactory: 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.OneToMany.orphanRemoval()Z
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:1893)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(AnnotationBinder.java:767)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:686)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3540)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3494)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1379)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1784)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:914)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:899)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:59)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:110)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:83)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answer: I just had to remove the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Took -me -hours! would vote up 2x if possible. Thanks a lot.